# Pass javascript variable to php

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

I know this had been disputed a lot and the short answer would be that I can't simply pass a javascript variable to a php variable in the same file. So instead here would be what I want to try: My user inputs a code, I send it to a php file by `POST`. There I check if the code matches a code from my database and I post again a boolean from there. Then in my first file, I tell the user whether the code is correct or not. Can this be achieved this way? I am a webdev newbie and I am trying to learn.

Comment: Yes you can do that with ajax post.

Comment: *I know this had been disputed a lot* - What has?

Comment: Short answer would be that you can't? Ever heard of [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))?

Comment: you can achieve this using `AJAX`.

Comment: I was refering to passing javascript variable to php variable

Comment: Do you mean the variable name, not the variable value?

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) objects are tailor made for this sort of thing. In fact, here's the [docs on the PHP implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Comment: @DerekHenderson I mean the variable value

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html)

Comment: @NegreaStefan, yeah, that's what we all assumed. It's just your comment ("I was refering to passing javascript variable to php variable") is confusing.  You've been given the answer by several users:  You have to post the variable to the server, and to do this without leaving the page you have to use AJAX.

Comment: I will edit my question, I'll try to clear things out

Comment: Looks like user @cernunnos was faster. That is what I am trying to do, please take a look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$.get( url, { userinput: value }, function( response ) {
    if( response.status ) alert( "Matches found" );
    else alert( "No matches" );
}
```

javascript:

```
function get( url ) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url,  false );
  xhr.send();
  return xhr.responseText;
}

var response = JSON.parse( get( url ) );
if( response.status ) alert( "Matches found" );
else alert( "No matches" );
```

php:

```
header( 'Content-type: text/json' );
if( get_matches( $_GET['userinput'] ) ) exit( '{ "status": true }' );
else exit( '{ "status": false }' );
```

Comment: For the total novitiate: the `$.get()` syntax requires jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a value from the client side to the server you can either send it on the URL or as a post variable.

This can be accomplished easily with ajax.

I recommend using jquery. example:

```
$.get("http://example.com/?var1=value&var2=othervalue", function (data) {
  // your response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post that code through AJAX to your server, have your server return a boolean, and then output a message to your user, this is quite common.

Common implementations of this logic include autosuggest, username validity verifications, simple turn on / turn off interfaces, etc.

Workflow:

- User inputs code
- Javascript sends AJAX request to server
- Server verifies code and returns boolean
- Javascript reads boolean, generates HTML and appends it to the document
- User reads output

Edit: Even though i advice you to try doing it with pure javascript first (for educational reasons), you should use jQuery or other equivalent framework if you are on a schedule.

Comment: Yeah- well that's what I'm trying to do. The part I don't know how to do is how to read the boolean with javascript

Comment: Oh, you want the actual code? im sure you can find a truckload of tutorials out there for this, as it is a trivial ajax application

Comment: No, I did not expect the actual code. Just a hint on how to read the bool with js

Comment: Assuming your server returns 1, 0, true or false: $.post(url, data, function (result) { if (result) {/*true*/} else {/*true*/} });